# Emacs customize-face loses/fails to recognise font-name it wrote to my .emacs itself

Tags: emacs, fonts, customization, emacs-faces

I used the Options/Set Default Font menu item to set my default emacs font to be LMMonoLtCond10 (it brought up a nice font-selector GUI widget to let me do this).  My emacs immediately adopted the new font, and I was very happy.  I then did Options/Save Options, and on inspecting my .emacs.d/init.el file saw that it had written the following there:

```
(custom-set-faces
;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
'(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "black"     
  :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal   
  :weight light :height 120 :width normal :foundry "unknown" :family "LMMonoLtCond10"))))
```

(There are a couple of other faces I've defined below that.)

Unfortunately, if I quit emacs, and restart, it completely fails to recreate the font configuration that I had selected.  Instead, I think it's giving me LMRoman-12.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this an emacs bug.

I'm using Emacs 23.1.1:

```
(emacs-version)
"GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (i486-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.20.1)
of 2011-03-05 on palmer, modified by Debian"
```

on an Ubuntu system.

Comment: Any messages concerning the face in *Messages* ?

Comment: Sadly, there's nothing reported in _Messages_ when I start up.

Comment: The shell command fc-list doesn't mention `LMMonoLtCond`, so this is perhaps a suggestion that I shouldn't be using it, even though it does appear in the dialog that emacs brings up.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be a bug.  `M-x report-emacs-bug`